# FFmpeg -bash: ffmpeg: command not found

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg, centos

OK, so I have gone up and down the internet trying to figure out what it is I am doing wrong ... and yet I'm in the middle of nowhere.
I am basically trying to install the **FFmpeg** on my **CENTOS 6.6** dedicated server by following the instructions here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Everything seems to go just fine throughout the process. When it's all done, I type in "ffmpeg" hit the enter and keep on getting this extremely ugly error:

> -bash: -bash:: command not found

I'm not much of a shell guy, but working with it all day today, I can say that this means that it's not installed correctly. So, I tried re-installing it, and it tells me all the packages already exist now ... . Here is a copy if what I am doing and what I am getting:

```
root@server1 [~]# ffmpeg -version
-bash: ffmpeg: command not found

root@server1 [~]# yum install autoconf automake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make nasm pkgconfig zlib-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ndchost.com
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * updates: mirrors.easynews.com
Package autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.81-20.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package nasm-2.07-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is off topic here but on topic for [SU]. I've voted to migrate it, so please don't post it again. In the future, please ask your regular command-line questions that are not exclusive to programming there. Thanks.

Comment: Learning something new every day ... Thanks @slhck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after paying more attention, I realized that there was an error

```
Unable to create and execute files in /tmp.  Set the TMPDIR environment
variable to another directory and make sure that it is not mounted noexec.
Sanity test failed.
```

So, I just made the /tmp directory and ran this:

```
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
```

And then ran the installation command!